# Does django support separating your templates into parts?

Tags: django

I would like to create separate templates for each part of the page like Navigation, Side bar, Login panel, etc. Django seems to use inheritance rather than composition. I was wondering if there is any support for separating templates out into parts and passing in template specific models to each template. I'm thinking of something like:

values = {
'navbar_data' = ...
'sidebar_data' = ...
}

{{ template.render('navbar', navbar_data) }}
{{ template.render('sidebar', sidebar_data) }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many good ways to do this.

You can use the builtin templatetage `include` for this.  This template tag allows you to to use and reuse specific fragments of a template.  This is usually most useful for mini templates that say represent a single model and will be used throughout the site.  This can be especially useful if you combine it with the `with` templatetag to allow you to craft the context used in the included template

Alternatively just simply using `block` may give you the feel you're looking for

Finally you can use custom inclusion templatetags (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) to give you an even deeper level of control.  These will allow you to render a subtemplate with a completely custom context.

Answer (score 0):

That is what templatetags are for.  You define a tag in a file called myapp/templatetags/mytags.py, then in your template do this

```
{% load mytags %}

{% navbar %} {% sidebar %}
```

The official documentation has plenty of information about this.